# Possible lack of RAM crashes application?

Tags: android, memory-management, ram

I am currently developing a quite simple Android 2D game. For testing, I have two Android devices:

- **ZTE Blade**
- **Huawei u8650**

My game runs fine in the **ZTE** but crashes after a bit of loading in the **Huawei** while the loading screen is showing.

I know **Huawei u8650** has small **RAM memory** but I have managed to free at least **70 megs** from it (checked programmatically at runtime) and my game does not use that much by far.

As today I am quite clueless.

Could anyone bring some light and tell us what else could be happening here?

I appreciate your help. Thanks.

Comment: Please share more information. E.g. what is the error message when your app crashes?

Comment: If possible please attach the crash log and stack trace, that helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can :

1. Check you application for memory leaks
2. If you are sure there's nothing to be optimized, you can use `android:largeHeap="true"` attribute in the `application` tag of your `Android Manifest`